# Send return value to dialog from thread MFC

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I'm creating dialog with do modal:

```
MainHamsterDlg MainHamsterDlg;
 if (MainHamsterDlg.DoModal() == IDCANCEL)
 break;
```

Then in that dialog create worker thread:

```
BOOL MainHamsterDlg::OnInitDialog()
    {
        AfxBeginThread(WorkerThreadProc, m_hWnd, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, 0, NULL);
        CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

        return TRUE;
    }
```

the thread must exit dialog by sending return value IDCANCEL.

```
    UINT WorkerThreadProc(LPVOID Param) //Sample function for using in AfxBeginThread
    {
        Sleep(1000); // process simulation
        MainHamsterDlg * self = (MainHamsterDlg *)Param;
        self->EndDialog(IDCANCEL);
        return FALSE;
    }
```

When compiling I do not get any error. when processing then getting on the point:

```
self->EndDialog(IDCANCEL);
```

error message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x01503AD4 in L2Hamster.exe: 0xC0000005:
Access violation reading location 0x00000020.
```

that pointing my to dlgcore.cpp file:

```
void CDialog::EndDialog(int nResult)
{
    ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); <<<<<===== to that line

    m_bClosedByEndDialog = TRUE;

    if (m_nFlags & (WF_MODALLOOP|WF_CONTINUEMODAL))
        EndModalLoop(nResult);

    ::EndDialog(m_hWnd, nResult);
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. any solution?

Comment: i'd pass just the window handle to the thread, then have the thread PostMessage the WM_COMMAND IDCANCEL to that handle when it's done so that the window processing is handled only on the main message queue.

Comment: can u post some example code?

Comment: now that i look closer at your code... it appears you're not sending anything in the AfxBeginThread pParam parameter... put the hWnd there.  also, in your example the thread ends immediately... it's possible your thread ends before the window is fully created.  PostMessage( hWnd, WM_COMMAND, IDCANCEL, 0 );

Comment: I edited little bit code can u look at it again? PostMessage( hWnd, WM_COMMAND, IDCANCEL, 0 ); how send to thread hWnd

Comment: UINT WorkerThreadProc(LPVOID Param) { Sleep(1000); PostMessage( (HWND)Param, WM_COMMAND, IDCANCEL, 0 ); return FALSE; }

Comment: Thank you the better solution for my is call thread AfxBeginThread(WorkerThreadProc, this, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, 0, NULL); and then in worker thread MainHamsterDlg* self = (MainHamsterDlg  *)Param;
 self->PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, IDCANCEL, 0);

Comment: Sorry some MFC folks are grumpy, someone has given you -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you intended to pass a pointer to the dialog to the thread proc. But you passed null instead:

```
 AfxBeginThread(WorkerThreadProc, NULL, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, 0, NULL);
```

Should be:

```
 AfxBeginThread(WorkerThreadProc, this, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, 0, NULL);
```

You will also need to coordinate the end of the thread with the end of the dialog to ensure the dialog isn't dismissed before the thread ends. (I assume it is some sort of progress dialog).

Comment: I'm edited the code by putting m_hWnd to thread call but still getting same error.

Comment: @klasik, You need to pass `this` to the thread if you are casting as a CDialog.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it is the problem to me:

```
AfxBeginThread(WorkerThreadProc, NULL, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, 0, NULL);
```

followed by

```
UINT WorkerThreadProc(LPVOID Param) //Sample function for using in AfxBeginThread
{
    MainHamsterDlg * self = (MainHamsterDlg *)Param;
        self->EndDialog(IDCANCEL);
    ...
}
```

Here, `Param` is `NULL`, so `self` is `NULL`.  You then dereference a null pointer.

Comment: then edit to cast to a `HWND` instead of a `MainHamsterDlg *`... then use PostMessage instead of self->EndDialog